# Theorem (Rellich) - Perturbation Theory

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, perturbation-theory

I got stuck with part of a proof of: [image: Theorem (Rellich)] The steps are all clear to me, until it is said:

"Therefore $f_w$ is the eigenvector of $ A+wB$ associated with the eigenvalue lying within for all small enough $w$".

[image: Part 1]
[image: Part 2]

I cannot carry out the calculations that allow me to prove that $f_w$ is an eigenvector of $A+wB$, nor to prove that there is an associated eigenvalue $\lambda_w$. I attach the specifications of the theorem found on page. 31-32 of Linear Operators and their Spectra (Davies).

Thank you in advance for your attention

Comment: Where exactly is the problem in the calculations? Since $P_w$ is the projection onto an eigenspace of $A+w B$ it follows at once that $f_w : = P_w f$ is an eigenvector, because $P_wf \neq 0$.

Comment: More precisely $P_w$ is the projection onto the eigenspace associated to the eigenvalue of $A+wB$ contained in $\gamma$.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that the image of the projection was onto the eigenspace.

Answer (score 0):

I write here, as prosecution of the question. I’d like to understand why holds $\forall \phi\in\mathfrak{B}^{*}$ such that $<f,\phi>=1$. Thanks in advance.

[image: Theorem (Rellich)]
[image: Proof]
[image: Proof]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I added the Theorem and the proof.